# reinitialize flexselect.js after adding new select controls with javascript

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to make use of flexselect.js to make select boxes easier to use and jquery.formset.js to dynamically add new formset forms.

[image]

I am making use of inline formsets here. The top-most row is the form while the fields in the grey box and formset form fields.
The input fields with "-----------" are select boxes that flexselect.js has converted to input fields.

Everything works well until I add a new formset form with JQuery(`jquery.formset.js`) by clicking "Add Item" on my UI.

[image]

A new form is added by `jquery.formset` as expected but the first field (the one I highlighted red) is not properly loaded by `flexselect.js`, hence its blank instead of containing "------------" like the one on top of it (the one I highlighted in yellow). When I click the input field, focus leaves the input field and goes to the field highlighed in yellow. In short, flexselect only works for select boxes that were present when flexselect was first initialized.

Can anyone tell me how to reinitialize `flexselect` whenever I add a new formset form so that flexselect stops ignoring freshly added select boxes.

I'm adding relevant code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // This initializes flexselect
        $("select.flexselect").flexselect();

        // this initializes jquery.formset.js and is used for adding new formset forms
        $(".inline.{{ posting_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ posting_form.prefix }}",
            addText: "Add item",
            deleteText: "Remove",
            added: function(){  // called when the formset form has been added
                $('select.flexselect').flexselect();
                // maybe some more code here.......
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution to the above problem. It had to do with the way `jquery.formset.js` works. In case someone else hits this brick, here's how I fixed it.

When you click "Add Item", `jquery.formset.js` knows the container which contains your initially displayed formset forms. It then follows this algorithm:

1. Clone one of the formset forms
2. Add it to the DOM after the last formset form container
3. Recalculate and change `id`, `name` and other attributes
4. etc

`flexselect.js` on the other hand works by looking for specified `select` tags in the DOM and adding some data to them.

By adding cloned `select`s that had already been manipulated back to the DOM was what was causing the unexpected behavior.

I couldn't think of any better way than modify the source code of `jquery.formset.js`. I changed it like this (starting at line 75):

```
$addBtn.click(function() {
            var nextIndex = parseInt($('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            var row = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':first').clone(true).get(0);
            $(row).removeAttr('id').insertAfter($('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last'));
            $(row).find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, options.prefix, nextIndex);
                // If this is a checkbox or radiobutton, set uncheck it.
                // Fix for Issue 1, reported by Wilson.Andrew.J:
                var elem = $(this);
                if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                    elem.attr('checked', false);
                } else {
                    elem.val('');
                }
            });
            var formCount = nextIndex + 1;
            $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount);
            // If we've got more than one form, enable delete buttons:
            if (formCount > 1) { $('a.' + options.deleteCssClass).show(); }
            // If a post-add callback was supplied, call it with the added form:
            if (options.added) options.added($(row));
            return false;
        });
```

to.....

```
$addBtn.click(function() {
            var nextIndex = parseInt($('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            var row = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':first').clone(true).get(0);
            // formset.js does not know that the form has been manipulated by flexselect.js. By cloning the form as
            // it is, it clones elements that have already had events and stuff attached to them. This is what
            // causes the weird behavior with flexselect.js

           // first we'll remove the class and style attributes
            $(row).find('select.flexselect').last().removeAttr("class style");
           // next, remove the input field that was previously generated by flexselect
            $(row).find('input.flexselect').remove();

            $(row).removeAttr('id').insertAfter($('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last'));
            $(row).find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, options.prefix, nextIndex);
                // If this is a checkbox or radiobutton, set uncheck it.
                // Fix for Issue 1, reported by Wilson.Andrew.J:
                var elem = $(this);
                if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                    elem.attr('checked', false);
                } else {
                    elem.val('');
                }
            });

            // At this point, formset.js has done most of the major lifting. We can now add the attributes that
            // flexselect.js needs which is just a select with a CSS class called 'flexselect'.
            $(row).find("select").attr("class", "flexselect");
            var formCount = nextIndex + 1;
            $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount);
            // If we've got more than one form, enable delete buttons:
            if (formCount > 1) { $('a.' + options.deleteCssClass).show(); }
            // If a post-add callback was supplied, call it with the added form:
            if (options.added) options.added($(row));
            return false;
        });
```

And then I adjusted the initializing code as thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("select.flexselect").flexselect();

        $(".inline.{{ posting_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ posting_form.prefix }}",
            addText: "Add item",
            deleteText: "Remove",
            added: function(){
                $('select.flexselect').last().removeData("flexselect");
                $('select.flexselect').flexselect();
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is how I fixed it. Hope it helps someone else.